# How to deal with co-linearity of dummy variables for linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I am using `scikit-learn` `LogisticRegression` on a dataset of household characteristics and trying to understand how to prepare the independent variables.

I have created binary dummy variables in place of categorical variables. 
e.g. The variable `DWELLING_TYPE` which had 3 possible values `DetachedHouse`, `SemiDetached` and `Apartment` has been replaced with 3 binary variables `DWELLING_TYPE_DetachedHouse`, `DWELLING_TYPE_SemiDetached` and DWELLING_TYPE_Apartment`that each has the value`1`or`0`.

Clearly these 3 variables are co-dependent (co-linear?) because if one of these variables is `1`, the other 2 must be `0`. My understanding is that co-linearity should be minimised for Logistic Regression, so should I be omitting one of these variables from the input matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a good practice. When you convert your categorical variables into dummies you can drop one of the dummies. It will reduce the redundancy from your input features.

In python you can do it by using `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_columns, drop_first=True)
```

setting **drop_first** parameter as **True** will work for you.