# Categorical dependent variable in Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I am using `scikit-learn LogisticRegression` on a dataset where the dependent variable is a categorical variable with 10 possible values (labelled 1 to 10). My statistical knowledge is fairly rudiemntatry.

The probabilities of each output value are inherently constrained by the requirement that they must sum to `1`, and my understanding of the maths is that there needs to be a `reference category` (e.g. the most likely category) and that the probability of each of the other 9 outcomes is then expressed relative to the probability of the reference category, so effectively there are 9 coefficients (rather than 10) for each explanatory variable.

I'm not clear whether this is done automatically by the `LogisticRegression.fit()` method, and if so does it assume the first category is the reference (`1`)? 
or do I need to somehow process the input data so there are only 9 categories?
or do I ignore this and use the 10 coefficients as they are output?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to create the dummies variables before using `LogisticRegression.fit()`, otherwise the `fit` function will treat that categorical variable as continuous one.

Comment: I think dummy variables are used for the independent (explanatory) variables, not for the dependent variable.

Comment: oh sorry, I mis-read your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scikit-learn` implementation of `LogisticRegression` automatically takes care of all that behind the scenes with its `.fit()` method. That's the main reason it is such a useful module. Their fit/transform/predict API is intuitive and easy to use, hiding all the algorithmic complexity from the user.

Their implementation is a One-vs-Rest scheme, where for each category a classifier is trained to identify the value as in that category or not in it with some confidence level. To make a prediction, the various confidences across the classifiers (10 classifiers in your case) are compared, and the class with the highest confidence is selected. To compute probabilities, this vector of confidences is normalized to 1 to account for any potential errors in predictions.

There is also a `multiclass` keyword argument which uses cross-entropy loss to directly to predict the probabilities for all 10 classes simultaneously with one classifier. This is probably more akin to the implementation you've read about, but the documentation on `scikit-learn`'s implementation thereof is sparse.

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698382/how-to-deal-with-co-linearity-of-dummy-variables-for-linear-regression) one?